# Configuring server name in Tomcat in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have developed a web application on a local system using eclipse and Tomcat server and hence I gave host name as "localhost". Now I want deploy the same application on windows server 2008 R2 and the server name is "miz-01.nhtf.ds".

How can I configure the tomcat with this server name so that my group within the institute can accesses my web application with help of this serve name. For an example "miz-01.nhtf.ds/login.jsp"

Comment: when you install it on that machine, `miz-01.nhtf.ds` *is* localhost.

Comment: @pennstatephil How other user from their computer can access my application. for an example, how can they access login.jsp page..I mean what is the URL they have to type to access the login.jsp

Comment: Have them access it through the ip address i.e. `146.186.50.88:8080/app/login.jsp`